# Bootstrapping the data to set up a prior

Tags: bootstrap, prior, resampling, conjugate-prior, empirical-bayes

I am using a Gaussian model with a conjugate Normal-Inverse-Wishart (NIW) prior, as described [here](https://www.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs281/papers/murphy-2007.pdf). The advantage of this approach is that the marginal likelihood $p(y)$, which is what I am interested in, is available in closed form.

My problem is that the results seem to be dependent of the NIW hyper-parameters (I have no prior information), with some of the dangers being described [here](http://dahtah.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/why-an-inverse-wishart-prior-may-not-be-such-a-good-idea/).

As an alternative, I am considering bootstrapping my data in order to obtain $m$ estimate of the mean and covariance. Then I could calculate the marginal likelihood:

$$
p(y) \approx \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m p(y|\hat{\mu}_i, \hat{\Sigma}_i).
$$

Would this prior be an approximation to an Empirical Bayes prior, something else or just nonsense?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered simply applying a scaling to the covariance matrix, [as suggested by Andrew Gelman](http://andrewgelman.com/2012/08/22/the-scaled-inverse-wishart-prior-distribution-for-a-covariance-matrix-in-a-hierarchical-model/)?

See also [this paper](http://simpsonm.public.iastate.edu/BlogPosts/ScaledInverseWishart/omalley.pdf) on the scaled inverse Wishart.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was doing originally. Then I tried to get a prior that depended only on the data (by bootstrapping), in order to avoid choosing a prior and its hyper-parameters.